# Do Venezuelan passport holders need a visa to transit through Santiago, Chile?

Tags: chile, venezuela, venezuelan-citizens

I am looking to organize a flight for my friend who is a Venezuelan passport holder, coming from Panama, to visit me here in Australia

I already had to cancel one flight because it went through the USA, and she doesn't have a USA visa.

The only other option is through Santiago, Chile.

I am doing some research to find out if she needs a visa to connect to a Sydney flight at Santiago.

I found this...

http://www.balglobal.com/bal-news/venezuelan-nationals-must-obtain-visas-before-entering-chile/

The post clearly states for tourist purposes in Chile, Venezuelans need a visa - but I can't get any confirmation about transit only policy through Santiago airport for connection of international flights.

No one answers the Chile embassy phone here in Australia and I can't get any solid confirmation online.

Can anybody provide some clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, says no transit visa is needed for a Venezuelan national to transit Chile airside:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
>   ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They
>   must stay in the international transit area of the airport and
>   have documents required for the next destination.

Obviously she will need to have her visa for Australia already.

Answer (score 6):

Chile has for Venezuelan citizens new immigration rules:

like ***Visto Consular de Turismo (VCT)*** and ***Visa De Responsabilidad Democrática  (VRD)***

but for her on Transit by plane, there is no visa required:
I quote from an official FAQ site: ([from here](https://serviciosconsulares.cl/tramites/preguntas-frecuentes-sobre-visto-consular-de-turismo-para-ciudadanos))

> 12- Si soy ciudadano venezolano y paso por Chile es una escala aérea o
> viajo en bus, pero mi destino final es otro país ¿Debo tener Visto
> Consular de Turismo?
>
> R: Vía terrestre: Sí. Al hacer la escala debe
> hacer cumplir la ley migratoria, salvo en los casos que existan
> convenios bilaterales en materia de residencia.
>
> **Vía aérea: No, no**
> **requiere visto consular de turismo para tránsito.**

In English:

> 12- If I am a Venezuelan citizen and I pass through Chile, it is an
> air stopover or I travel by bus, but my final destination is another
> country. Should I have Consular Tourism Visa?
>
> A: By land: Yes. When making the stopover you must enforce the
> immigration law, except in cases where there are bilateral agreements
> on residence.
>
> **By air: No, it does not require a tourist consular visa for transit.**